# why SetSel and clear functions are used in editBox in order to write text

Tags: c++, mfc, overwrite, editbox, editcontrol

Suppose I have an editBox with text "this is edit",

and then I want to change that text to "second"

I think it is okay to code just like this:

```
m_edit1.SetWindowTextW(_T("this is edit"));

m_edit1.SetWindowTextW(_T("second"));
```

but I saw other program that they use like this:

```
m_edit1.SetWindowTextW(_T("this is edit"));

m_edit1.SetSel(0, -1, TRUE);
m_edit1.Clear();

m_edit1.SetWindowTextW(_T("second"));
```

**My question is**:

why they're using `SetSel()`, `Clear()`   in this case if we can just overwrite it like first code example??

Comment: You would have to ask the author who wrote the code that is doing that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there's a distant possibility that someone else knows the corner case this pattern is supposed to protect against.  That wouldn't be me though.

Comment: It would make sense to link to the said article as a reference point.

Comment: @MarkRansom the only possibility I can think of is to support the use of `CEdit::Undo()` (`EM_UNDO`), since `CWnd::SetWindowText()` (`WM_SETTEXT`) can't be undone, but `CEdit::SetSel()` (`EM_SETSEL`) and `CEdit::Clear()` (`WM_CLEAR`) can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code

```cpp
m_edit1.SetSel(0, -1, TRUE);
m_edit1.Clear();
```

serves no practical purpose, in the context given above. While `m_edit1.Clear()` sends a [`WM_CLEAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clear) message to the control that

> can be undone by sending the edit control an [EM_UNDO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-undo) message

that opportunity is gone once `m_edit1.SetWindowTextW(L"second")` has run to completion. In summary, there's no difference in observable behavior between executing the first and second snippet of code in the question. They both result in an edit control holding the text `"second"` with an empty undo queue.

If indeed the intent was to support undo operations, the code would need to be adjusted to send an [`EM_REPLACESEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-replacesel) message in place of `WM_SETTEXT`:

```cpp
m_edit1.SetWindowTextW(L"this is edit");

m_edit1.SetSel(0, -1, TRUE);
m_edit1.ReplaceSel(L"second", TRUE);
```

This leaves the edit control showing the text `"second"`, but with a non-empty undo queue. Sending an `EM_UNDO` message to the control will have it show `"this is edit"` again. Note that an edit control's undo queue has a length of no more than one.